# Gremlin: project().by() want to reduce number of traversals

Tags: gremlin

I have a Gremlin query in which I want to report certain statistics about families in a school setting.  For each parent, I want to calculate certain statistics about their family: number of boys/girls, number of children attending STEM classes, etc.  I'm using project().by() to ensure that I'm reporting statistics for every parent, even if they don't have qualifying children (such as parents whose children are not yet in school).

My query begins with finding the parents.  However, when I try to get the list of their children, all of my statistics are for all children, rather than just the children for a particular parent.  I get the right statistics for children by parent if the traversal steps to find the children are executed inside the by() step.  But this means that I have to duplicate those traversal steps inside each of the by() steps.

My query looks something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Parent').
    project('Parent', 'boys', 'girls', 'STEM_students', 'sport_participants').
    by('name').
    by( <traversal to find parent's children>.
        <filter parent's boys>.count()).
    by( <traversal to find parent's children>.
        <filter parent's girls>.count()).
    by( <traversal to find parent's children>.
        <filter parent's STEM students>.count()).
    by( <traversal to find parent's children>.
        <filter parent's sports students>.count())
```

I get the right answers in this query, but have to run the traversal to find each parent's children four times.  I'd like to run that traversal once per parent.  Suggestions on how to reform my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the children traversal by parents and then you can use the folded list directly to run further traversals without having to run children traversal again and again in the project-by modulators.

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('Parent').
  group().by().by(<traversal_to_find_children>).
  unfold().as('data').
  select('values').as('grouped_children').
  select('data').select(keys).
  project('Parent','boys','girls','STEM_students','sport_participants').
    by('name').
    by(
      select('grouped_children').
      unfold().
      <traversal_to_find_boys>.count()).
    by(
      select('grouped_children').
      unfold().
      <traversal_to_find_girls>.count()).
    by(
      select('grouped_children').
      unfold().
      <traversal_to_find_stem_students>.count()).
    by(
      select('grouped_children').
      unfold().
      <traversal_to_find_sports_students>.count())
```

Comment: I've removed the quotes in the select(values) step, as I get no data with the quotes.  Now, however, I'm only getting data on the first child for each parent, not all of their children.  What am I missing?

Comment: yeah thanks for changing values from quotes to without quotes. Can you try a fold after the <traversal_to_find_children> ?

Comment: The additional fold helps, but I get an error when trying to produce the parent name (I've not yet added the counts traversals to my result set):  The by("name") modulator can only be applied to a traverser that is an Element or a Map

Comment: .fold().
unfold().as('data').
select(values).as('grouped_children').select('data').select(keys).
project('parent').
      by('name')

Comment: Following the error message, I get a list of all of the parent vertices

Comment: Putting an unfold() after the select(keys) will give me the correct values for Parent names.

Comment: If you are still not sorted, please provide a sample dataset and query you have. I ll have a look whats missing. Conceptually above query should have worked after fold in child finding traversal.

Answer (score 0):

My updated query:

```
    g.V().
        hasLabel('Parent').
        group().by().by(<traversal_to_find_children>).
        unfold().as('data').
        select(values).as('grouped_children').
        select('data').select(keys).unfold().
        project('Parent','boys','girls','STEM_students','sport_participants').
            by('name').
            by(
               select('grouped_children').
               unfold().
               <traversal_to_find_boys>.count()).
            by(
               select('grouped_children').
               unfold().
               <traversal_to_find_girls>.count()).
            by(
               select('grouped_children').
               unfold().
               <traversal_to_find_stem_students>.count()).
            by(
               select('grouped_children').
               unfold().
               <traversal_to_find_sports_students>.count())
```

The work isn't done yet (I'm still working on the counts), but I'm seeing progress.